# Getting the value of textFields using their tag

Tags: iphone, tags, uitextfield

I have created some textFields dynamically:

```
    for (int a=0; a<10; a++) {
    UITextField *textField =[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 20+50*a , 160, 31)];
            [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            [textField setTag:a+1];
            [textField setDelegate:self];
            [self.view addSubview:textField];
            [textField release];
}
```

Now I have to get the values of their on a button click using their tag. How can I make this ?

Comment: Your tagging scheme is going to bite you in the ass. I'd recommend declaring this `UITextField` in the header and then synthesizing the property. Set it, then you can access it globally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get your textfields later using `-viewWithTag:` method:

```
- (void) buttonClick:(id)sender{
   for (int a=0; a<10; a++) {
       UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:a+1];
       NSString *fieldValue = textField.text;
       NSLog(@"Field %d has value: %@", a, fieldValue);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `viewWithTag:` method of `UIView` to get the subview with the tag you want.
From there you can cast it to a `UITextField` and use the `text` property to get the value.